# Why would a page created by a custom module work in my DEV environment, but produce a 404 on the live server?

Tags: 8, plugins

I have a custom module that's creating feeds of my content for me. It's been running fine up until now. Existing feeds work, and the new feed I just added works on my development site on my local mac.

The problem I'm having is that after uploading the code changes to create the new feed to the live server, I'm getting a drupal 404 error.

So, for example: 
feed 1: /rss/yahoo.xml works on both DEV and LIVE

but

feed 2: /rss/amazon.xml works on DEV, but on Live produces a drupal 404 error.

I've cleared the cache, both all at once, and one at a time.

I've downloaded the live database back down to DEV to see if that breaks it, but the feed continues to work on the live site.

I've checked the live server's error logs to see if it's throwing any errors related to the URL at all, but I don't see any.

I've reinstalled the module that's generating the pages, to no effect.

I've confirmed all the files I meant to upload did in fact upload, and didn't get prevented from uploading due to permissions conflicts.

I've viewed the updated files directly on the web server to confirm, they are indeed supposed to be generating the feed.

The feed is programmed nearly identically to other existing, working feeds. The only difference between feed 1 (working) and feed 2 (only working on dev) is that feed 2 pulls a few new custom fields. I've confirmed the custom fields have been created on the live server, as they are on the dev server. Doubally confirmed when I synced the live database down to the dev site.

I'm flat out of ideas as to why the new feed isn't working when the nearly identical old feed is working, and as to why it functions in one environment and not the other.

I know it's an odd question, but has anyone experienced anything like this?

Below are the relevant code excerpts:

(from lmfeed.routing.yml)

```
misc.rss.amazon:
  path: '/rss/amazon.xml'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\lmfeed\Controller\LmfeedMiscController::miscAmazonXml'
    _format: xml
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE
```

(From LmfeedMiscController.php)

```
  public function miscAmazonXml() {
    $data = (object) [
      'title'       => '<my domain name>',
      'description' => '<my feed description>',
      'nodes'       => [],
    ];
    foreach ($this->dbh->selectVideos(self::RPP) as $nid) {
      $node = $this->entityMgr->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

      if (!empty($node)) {
        $data->nodes[] = [
          'title'    => $this->filterTxt($node->title->value),
          'body'     => $this->filterTxt($node->get('field_paragraph')->value),
      'body2'     => $this->filterTxt($node->get('field_paragraph')->value),
      //'body'   => $node->get('field_teaser')->value,
          'created'  => date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $node->created->value) . ' GMT',
          'guid'     => '<my domain name>' . $node->id(),
          'img'      => $this->getImgUrl($node, self::IMG_FIELD),
          'keywords' => $this->filterTxt($node->get('field_keywords')->value),
          'video'    => $node->get('field_vid_url')->getString(),
          'amazonfeatured'   => $node->get('field_amznfeaturedasin')->getString(),
          'amazonrep' => $node->get('field_amazon_representativ')->getString(),
          'amazdur' => $node->get('field_runtime')->getString(),
        ];
      }
    }
    return $this->render($data, 'lmfeed_misc_amazon_xml');
  }
```

from lmfeed.module amongst the other feed declaration statements

```
    'lmfeed_misc_amazon_xml' => [
      'template'  => 'lmfeed--misc-amazon-xml',
      'variables' => [
        'data' => [],
      ],
```

From lmfeed--misc-amazon.xml.html.twig

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss" xmlns:amzn="https://amazon.com/">
  <channel>
    <title>{{ data.title }}</title>
    <link>https://<my domain name>/rss/amazon.xml</link>
    <description>{{ data.description }}</description>
{% for node in data.nodes %}
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[{{ node.title|raw }}]]></title>
      <pubDate>{{ node.created }}</pubDate>
      <media:content url="{{ node.video }}" type="video/mp4" medium="video" duration="{{ node.amazdur }}" lang="en"/>
      <media:thumbnail url="{{ node.img }}"/>
      <media:keywords><![CDATA[{{ node.keywords|raw }}]]></media:keywords>
      <media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[{{ node.body|raw }}]]></media:description>
      <guid>{{ node.guid }}</guid>
      {% if node.amazonfeatured %}<amzn:featuredASIN>{{ node.amazonfeatured }}</amzn:featuredASIN>
      {% elseif node.amazonrep %}<amzn:representativeASIN>{{ node.amazonrep }}</amzn:representativeASIN>{% endif %}
    </item>
{% endfor %}
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Again, I don't THINK this is a code issue, since it works properly on my dev environment... I'm just out of ideas.

Comment: Route names should begin with the module’s name. E.g lmfeed.misc.rss.amazon.

Comment: Good to know, but that can't be where the problem is, because my other feeds are declared starting with "misc" and they work properly on both dev and live. For example: ``` misc.rss.yahoo:
  path: '/rss/yahoo.xml'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\lmfeed\Controller\LmfeedMiscController::miscYahooXml'
    _format: xml
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE ```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what happened. Before I updated my module with the new feed, I renamed the module folder from lmfeed to lmfeed_bak and then uploaded my new version into a new folder called lmfeed, thinking the feeds would break for a microsecond, and then Drupal would keep looking at contents of the same folder name it had been. Drupal however unexpectedly monitored the folder name change and continued using the version of the module now living in the lmfeed_bak folder. This is why the module continued to function, but didn't reflect any of my recent changes.

I figured this out from asking the server hosting company to run a STRACE on both the working feed and the nonworking feed. I've now removed the duplicate module, renamed the folder back to what it should be, applied my updated code, and it's functioning properly.